# Speeding printf and cout in windows

Tags: c++

Windows cout and printf is really slow, so when a lot of data is sent it slows applications (it happens with code running during days to check if all is working well).
A metod to make it faster is to use a buffer by writting following code at the beginning of the main() function:

```
#ifndef __linux__   //Introduce this code at the beginning of main() to increase a lot the speed of cout in windows: 
char buffer_setvbuf[1024];setvbuf(stdout, buffer_setvbuf, _IOFBF, sizeof buffer_setvbuf); //¿¡¡Sometimes it does not print cout inside a function until cout is used in main() or end of buffer is reached.
#endif
```

But unfortunately a side effect is that sometimes it does not print the data because the buffer is not full.

Then the questions:
1. How to force print: by making \n?
2. How to disable the buffer?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Comment: I don't understand part 2 of the question. Are you trying to set a buffer or not?

Comment: If you need to print data even when the buffer is not full, I believe `std::flush` is what you need.

Comment: MSalters: After setting the buffer, it is possible to disable it?    Croolman: thank you, I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 3):

## printf

I see you are trying to use larger buffer on memory to reduce the number of writes on `stdout`. Indeed, your code would not print anything until your buffer becomes full, because the buffering mode is set to `_IOFBF` (i.e. full buffering). Since you want control when to flush, there are two ways to go about.

1. Use `_IOLBF` (i.e. line buffering), and put newline character whenever you want to flush.
2. Call `fflush(stdout)` to manually flush the buffer.

## std::cout

I think `std::cout` should be preferred when writing c++ code, because of its ease of use. One thing that might slow down the I/O process is synchronization between `iostream` and `stdio`. As far as I know, the default on many systems is to keep the two in sync, and it has some overhead. You can disable it by calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`. [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/)

When you need to flush output, you can use what is called "manipulators" for output stream - namely `std::flush` and `std::endl`. When those manipulators are put into an output stream like the following: `std::cout << "your string" << std::endl`, it is guaranteed that the output stream is flushed.

`std::endl` [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)

`std::flush` [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

## Bottom Line

1. Use `fflush` to flush `stdout` when using `printf` for output.
2. I recommend trying `std::cout` with sync off, and test if it fits your performance need.

Comment: Does the '\n'  force the printf to flush the buffer?. I think it is better using the \n at the end of the sentence instead at the beginning

Comment: @mathengineer If you want printf's buffer to be flushed on newline, `_IOLBF` should be used instead of `_IOFBF`. Or you can use `fflush` to manually flush `stdout`. However, I recommend sticking with `std::cout` in c++ unless you have a good reason not to use it.